# Binding ImageSource of ImageBrush in UserControl to CodeBehind

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls

I created a user control that included a button.
I want to set, every time that I using the button, the path of the imagesource for the imagebrush-background.
for this I have do:
I create a depenedency property string- MyPath in the code beind.
in the xaml of the user control I wrote:

```
<Button>
   <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource={Binding MyPath}/> 
   </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

in the construct of the UserControl (xamk.cs) I wrote

```
DataContext=this;
```

the MainWindow is inside View directory and the path of the image is "ViewResources\Regular.png"

so in the MainWindow.xaml I wrote:

```
<vm:MyButton NyPath="Resources\Regular.png"/>
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: If the resource path really is "ViewResources\Regular.png", you should also write that in your XAML. Also, make sure that the Build Action of the image file is set to `Resource`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a name of your UserControl on the top of the xaml, and Bind it like that:

```
<Button>
  <Button.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource={Binding MyPath, ElementName="YourUserControlName"}/> 
  </Button.Background>
</Button>
```